# Json query result not getting set

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use a Json request to get data from a login screen. But no matter if the login request is valid or not, I am always getting returned to my home screen. I think I am checking the result incorrectly?

Basically, in my Twitter-Bootstrap enabled site, I have a modal popup that takes the user to a login form.

The values are passed via a json query, to my MVC4 controller. A breakpoint shows I am getting good data.

Here's the scrip that sends the data:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.btnSubmit').on('click', function () {
            var data = { username: $('.txtUsername').val(), password: $('.txtPassword').val(), rememberMe: $('.cbRemember').val() };

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("LoginUser", "User")',
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                cache: false,
                async: true,
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result['success'] == 'true') {
                        alert("true");
                        window.location = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';
                        } else {
                            alert("BAD");

                        }
                    },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Error in input");
                }

            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

And here is the controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult LoginUser(string username, string password, string rememberMe)
    {
        string success = "false";
        string message = "Not set";

        if (username == string.Empty || password == string.Empty)
        {
            success = "false";
            message = "Invalid Username/Password";
        }
        else
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var us = new UserService();
                var reply = us.Authenticate(username, Security.EncryptText(password));
                if (reply == 0)
                {
                    success = "false";
                    message = "Invalid Username/Password";
                }

                if (reply != 0)
                {
                    var p = us.GetPerson(reply);
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(p.Id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), rememberMe == "on");
                    Session["UserDisplay"] = string.Format("{0} {1} - ({2})", p.Firstname, p.Surname, p.Email);
                    success = "true";
                    message = "Login Success";
                }


            }
        }
        var result = new { Success = success, Message = message };
        var r = new JsonResult
            {
                Data = result
            };

        return r;
    }
```

However, I always get the 'BAD' alert. Never the 'true'.

Can I check the result the way I am? Am I attempting to do this the right way? Basically, if I get 'BAD', I don't want the screen to refresh. Infact, I will want to show a message saying what ever is in the 'message' parameter.

Edit: I think 'result' is NULL.

Comment: i think `result['success']` should be `result['Success']`, javascript property is case sensitive. And also you should prevent default action of form in click handler `$('.btnSubmit').on('click', function (e) { e.preventDefault();});`

Comment: I changed it, but still 'BAD' is always alerted. Is there a way to check if 'result' is null? I think it is.

Comment: add `console.log(result['Success']);` in ajax callback function(before if condition) and check the developer tools (F12) in firefox/chrome and check the console. you can check XHR subtab under the network tab in developer tools to see the raw ajax request/response.

Comment: OK, some progress. I see I can reference result.Success, and it reyurns the strings 'true' or 'false', but I can't reference result.Message in the same way.

Comment: If the `Success` works, `Message` should work too. Try console logging and using the XHR network tab to catch the problem.

Comment: Wow, I am learning about nice tools! I see in the response body, "{"Success":"false","Message":"Invalid Username/Password"}" But, I can't seem to reference 'Message'.

Comment: Fixed. I just reference 'result.Success' and it worked.